# GPO Deployment Status Reporting

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

My team and I have been doing some research to find a tool that can be used to report on the status of GPO deployments. We're seeking this for one of our customers but can't seem to find anything in the marketplace. To clarify, precisely, the type of reporting we're seeking, I'll share an analogy used by one of my team members and then depict how it is comparable to Group Policy (GP).

A mother writes a letter to each of her children with instructions for completing an online survey for their upcoming family reunion. She puts the letters in envelopes and then goes to the post office to get them mailed out with delivery confirmation. She assumes that if she gets confirmation that the letters arrived, her children (since they're such good kids) followed through with the request and completed the survey.

From a GP perspective, an IT administrator (mother) creates a GPO (envelope) and specifies the settings (instructions) that need to delivered to Windows systems (children). The Group Policy infrastructure (Post Office) gets the GPO to the workstation.

What we're looking for is something like delivery confirmation for GP. How do we know the GPO got to the systems? What time did it get there?

How have you been able to meet this requirement in your organization or for your customers?

If you're familiar with Client Management Systems such as SCCM, we're just looking for something similar to the reporting available in these tools to monitor the status of package deployments.

Indeed, we've been able to find tools in the market that can confirm whether settings were applied (if the survey got completed), but that's not what we're seeking.

If we can't find something, we may be tasked to create a solution. If we were to go that route, we'd rather build something that is commercially available than something that aids only one organization. How many of you would be interested in something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to determine the Resultant Set of Policy. If so, you can use the Group Policy Results wizard in the GPMC or Gpresult on any machine to give you the information.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I would have to do that on 100K systems and then aggregate the data. So It would not be the most efficient solution for me.